# Install two linux distribution Dual boot

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, fedora

I have planned to install two linux(Fedora) distributions.

For First Fedora installation, I have partition in this manner:

LVM volume group

```
VolGroup
    lv_root     /   ext4
    lv_swap         swap
    lv_home     /home   ext4
    Free
```

Hard drives

```
SDA
    SDA1    /boot       ext4
    SDA2    VolGroup    physical volume(LVM)
```

================================================================================
My intention is see the free space in the second Fedora installation,
But, It is NOT visible during second installation.

Please let me know what should be done to see this Free space so that I can install second Fedora installation ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have left one partition free while installing first Distribution.

Then , while installing second distribution, able to see the same partition. Then, I have just deleted that partition to see it as free space. Then, I have selected "Automatic partitioning" for second linux distribution and it is installed without any issues.

In addition, faced another issue where grub entry of first distribution was missing.
Able to restore the same using.

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

grub2-install /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

```
lvcreate --name fedora_root --size 100G VolGroup
lvcreate --name fedora_swap --size 10G VolGroup
```

The second line is only needed if you intend to suspend to disk one distribution before starting the other one.

Adapt the sizes: 10G to your amount of RAM memory, and 100G to the free space you want to give to Fedora.